# why it is costing longer than the first time to open USB2Serial port

Tags: c++, centos7, usbserial

I am testing the time cost of opening a `USB2Serial` port n Centos 7.4. But I found it cost about 7ms for the first time. But it cost much more time in the next opening. If I increase the sleep time, run again, it costs more time except for the first open.

I am using `usb2serial` device from FTDI, the kernel driver is ftdi_sio.

**Here is my code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    steady_clock::time_point start = steady_clock::now();
    int handle = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NONBLOCK | O_NDELAY);
    steady_clock::time_point end = steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Item " << i <<  ":" << " " << duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count()/1000000 << " ms" << endl;
    usleep(10000); // us
    close(handle);
}
```

**The result is:**

Item 0: 6 ms

Item 1: 76 ms

Item 2: 75 ms

Item 3: 75 ms

Item 4: 75 ms

Item 5: 76 ms

Item 6: 75 ms

Item 7: 75 ms

Item 8: 75 ms

Item 9: 74 ms

I just wonder why the open time becomes longer after the first time. Maybe need some other operation before close.

Anyone has met similar problem ? Or any comments? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`std::chrono::duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) returns a [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) ***object***.

The [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function is an old C compatibility function, and as such knows *nothing* about C++ objects.

In short, what you're printing is not really the duration, instead you have [*undefined behavior!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) Considering you're on Ubuntu, then you're using either GCC or Clang, both compilers which should complain about that.

If you want to print the actual duration "count" then use the [`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) member function, preferably together with `std::cout` to get type-safe conversions:

```
std::cout << "Item " << i << ": " << duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(e1-s1).count() << " ns\n";
```

Or if your compiler can handle some of the changes in the upcoming C++20 standard (which defines an [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_ltlt) overload for durations):

```
std::cout << "Item " << i << ": " << duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(e1-s1) << " ns\n";
```

---

The big lesson: Don't mix C++ and old C functions. They seldom mix very well.

You might also want to consider [getting a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to help you learn C++ properly.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will change it.

Comment: Have changed a little. But the open time still becomes longer after the firs open.